# Can we update the part of canvas without updating entire canvas?

Tags: android, image, android-canvas

I am extending the ImageView to display the images. The input stream for images is getting from socket along with their top left coordinates.

I am able to display the part of image,where as the remaining screen is white.My problem is total canvas is overridden with the current bitmap and the previous drawings are erased with white screen.

I searched for the solution,I come across to known the information about canvas is "Every pixel of canvas is drawn when canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,top,left,paint) is called".

I need to update the only dirty part of image(canvas) without updating the entire canvas.

Please suggest me How to update the dirty part of screen(canvas) and previous drawings should not be erased.

Thanks & Regards

Mini.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a canvas from what you already have instead creating a blank on and then draw on it. This is an example of how to achieve it.

```
yourImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = yourImageView.getDrawingCache();
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
```

Then you have a canvas, which contains whatever was previously in ImageView and you can update whatever part you want. For that I would recommend having a look at [PorterDuff modes](http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/).

Comment: I have gone through your suggestion and looked at PorterDuff modes. I am sorry to say I didn't get the post.

Comment: I am unable to draw bitmap with another canvas object. Able to draw with canvas object in onDraw(Canvas canvas). So How should I draw with the canvas, which have previous bitmaps?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The question was about updating a part of the canvas. Your solution requires creating the entire bitmap, even if it's from a cache.